# CentOS 7 install doesn't use up all free space for PV

Tags: centos, lvm

We recently installed CentOS 7.3 using LVM:

[image]

and creating the FHS (filesystem hierarchy):

[image]

as you can see the PV doesn't have the size of the disk by default.

Solution is to **additionally** (more clicks) set it to use up all the disk (because maybe later different FS on the rootvg, aka.: cl-root have to be increased, this is jut an example when there is only / ).

[image]

**The Question**: why isn't CentOS 7 using up all the free space for the PV by default?

Additionally from: https://access.redhat.com/articles/1190213

If someone installs the system without knowing this "trick" it will have to fix it later.. ex.:

/dev/sda2 is the partition on /dev/sda that is the PV for the LVM, so we will use "2". **this could differ in your situation!**

resizepart in parted is only supported from parted 3.2, and CentOS 7.3 DVD only has 3.1.

also from parted 2.4, there isn't any "resize" command...

so we will have to delete the partition with fdisk and create it again with **the same starting point**, but bigger ending... (data will remain on it, but it is advised to do this only offline!)

Ending is almost at the end of the disk, but fdisk will say what can it use max..

```
boot up a Centos 7.3 installer DVD -> Troubleshoot -> Rescue mode -> skip to shell

loadkeys hu # or whatever language you use

fdisk /dev/sda
print
d
2

n
p # if using MBR
2
enter # this will be the start, must be the same as the old start!
enter # this will be the max that fdisk can use up, it will say what is the max, the ~end of the disk

t
2
L
# 8e or 15 to select LVM type

w
q

# e2fsck the given FS (if ex.: EXT*)

sync; sync; sync
reboot
```

remove DVD, boot originally installed OS

```
pvs
pvresize /dev/sda2
pvs
```

info: parted works too of course! if you prefer that rather than fdisk.